# Set session/cookie for 24hs to show something only once per day to users

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've been searching for the last hour how to do this... I think it's pretty easy, but couldn't make it work.

I want to show something (AdSense) only once per day.

I don't know what would be the best way, if using cookies or PHP Sessions. In any case, can you help me and tell me how could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Santiago

Edit: I think this way I can create the Session, but I don't know how to "recreate" it each 24 hours and how to check for that session in order to show what I want to show once a day.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['adSense']) 
    $_SESSION['adSense'] = time();

if (time() - $_SESSION['adSense'] <= 60*60*24 ) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show us what you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: I tried a lot, I could paste a chunk of code that won't work but I don't know if it would be helpful.

Comment: Well, for the code that you've written, how doesn't it work? Does it set the cookie? Does it set the cookie, but the time stamp isn't working? Does the time stamp work, but things still appear?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sessions will expire when the user leaves the site, using cookies is what you want:

```
<? if (!isset($_COOKIE['showstuff'])): ?>

    <!-- replace this whatever you want to show -->

    <?
    setcookie('showstuff', true,  time()+86400); // 1 day
    ?>

<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: One question, can I do this one time in the header and check for the cookie each time I want to display something in my page? Because I want to show 3 different things in my page and I don't know if setting the cookie 3 times is right...

Comment: It will work no matter how many times you put the code (even with different content) on the same page. It will only set cookie once.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't it be cleaner to set the cookie only once and then check for it each time I want to show something?

Comment: Yes you can remove `setcookie` in subsequent placements.

Comment: Oh, now I understand! Sorry! Thanks again for the answer! ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this way.

1.

```
setcookie('showPopup','yes',time() + 24 * 3600); // 24 hours
```

2.

```
setcookie('showPopup','yes',strtotime( '+1 days' )); // 24 hours
```

3.

```
setcookie('showPopup','yes',time() + 86400); // 24 hours
```

Check Cookie

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['showPopup']))
{
     echo 'Not show pop';
}
else{           
    echo 'show popup and set cookie';
    setcookie('showPopup','yes', time() + 86400);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it the other way:

- You check for the existence of the cookie.
- if it's there, do nothing
- if it's not there, do what you want to do once a day, and create a cookie that expires 24 hours later.

Comment: exactly :) we answered at 2 minutes interval :)