# PHP Cookie for 1 day

Tags: php, wordpress, session-cookies

On my wordpress blog i want to show a popup on posts. I installed a plugin but it shows the popup for every time. I tried to change the code but didnt work. I dont know php well. Can you help me? I want to show popup only once per day.

```
if ( $timer && !empty( $show_timer ) && $show_timer == 'yes' && !isset($_COOKIE['html_ad']))

                $html_ad .= '<div id="popups-bar" ' . $style_bar . '>

                                    <div id="popups-tit" class="popups">' . $this->get_interad( $ad_id, 'title' ) . '</div>

                                    <div id="popups-close">

                                              <div id="inter-mess" ' . $bor_style . '>

                                                    <span> ' . $tra_wait . ' </span>

                                                    <span data-seconds="' . $countdown . '" class="popups-kkcount-down"></span>

                                                    <span> ' . $tra_until . ' </span>

                                              </div>    

                                    </div>

                            </div>';





            $html_ad .= '<div id="popups-cnt" ' . $style_cont . '>

                                ' . $this->get_interad( $ad_id ) . '

                         </div>



              </div><!-- Popup Plugin-->' . "\n";
            setcookie('html_ad', true,  time()+86400);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set session/cookie for 24hs to show something only once per day to users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099170/set-session-cookie-for-24hs-to-show-something-only-once-per-day-to-users)

Comment: What you mean by "didnt work"? It doesn't show? It shows popup every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setcookie("CookieName", $CookieValue, time()+86400);
```

This will set a cookie for 24 hours. You can change the time to any amount of time you want! Or try this for wordpress

```
setcookie("sevisitor", 1, time()+3600, "/", str_replace('http://www','',get_bloginfo('url')) );
```

As found here http://scratch99.com/wordpress/development/setting-cookies-in-wordpress-trap-for-beginners/